# При подключении файла в дочернюю тему wordpress получаю ошибку 500

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

У меня есть магазин на wordpress + woocommerce с темой flatastic. Мне нужно подключить конфигурационный файл тем `config.php` который лежит в теме по пути `themes/flatastic/config-woocommerce/config.php`. Делаю все 1 в 1 согласно [инструкции автора](https://velikorodnov.ticksy.com/articles/8174/?print)

```
/* Include Config WooCommerce
/ ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
if (class_exists('WooCommerce')) {
    if ( ! function_exists( 'mad_woo_config' ) ) {
    function mad_woo_config() {
        // Load required classes and functions
        require_once( 'config-woocommerce/config.php' );
        return MAD_WOOCOMMERCE_CONFIG::instance();
    }
}
/**
* Instance main plugin class
*/
    global $mad_woo_config;
    $mad_woo_config = mad_woo_config();
}
```

Но выбивает 500 ошибку..всю папку `config-woocommerce` с конфигом скопировал в дочернюю тему, путь в `require_once()` указываю правильный (подключение проверял на другом файле)
в логах пишет: `PHP Fatal error: call to undefined method MAD_WOOCOMMERCE_CONFIG::instance() in functions.php`
в чем может быть проблема? Сам файл config.php - [здесь](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8aa51d8b6bcfe3dde0f704ab9665f61c79673892)

Comment: как именно "ругается"? покажите сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: @AntonioK ошибка сервера 500 "на сайте произошла ошибка при получении страницы. Возможно, сайт временно недоступен или настроен неправильно"

Comment: это в браузере, а в логах что?

Comment: @Denis Startsev php fatal error: call to undefined function mad_custom_get_option() in config.php - ага, будем копать где создается эта функция

Comment: @Denis Startsev функции добавил, теперь ошибка такая `PHP Fatal error: call to undefined method MAD_WOOCOMMERCE_CONFIG::instance() in functions.php`

Comment: А точно используется нужная версия flatastic, просто в приведенном коде вы вызываете `MAD_WOOCOMMERCE_CONFIG::instance();` , а в ссылке с исходником этого метода нет. Попробуй его добавить вариант кода, добавил в ответ

Comment: @Denis Startsev да, точно - это инструкция подходит только для новой версии темы! вопрос закрыт, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вся загвоздка была в том, что инструкция подходила для новой версии темы, только в ней был реализован функционал для подключения конфигурационного файла в дочернюю тему

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать

```
require_once( __DIR__.'/config-woocommerce/config.php' );
```

Вариант метода instance, добавить можно перед `function __construct() {`

```
public static function instance () 
{
    if (!MAD_WOO_CONFIG)
    {
        return new MAD_WOOCOMMERCE_CONFIG();
    }

}
```

Comment: нее, к сожалению все тоже самое - дело явно не в пути, а невозможности подключения конфига таким способом..

Comment: `fatal error: cannot redeclare MAD_WOOCOMMERCE_CONFIG::instance() in config.php`